# Strange jquery mobile listview behavior whan used with knockout foreach

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I was trying to build a jQuery mobile, list view using a ko observableArray and found that some of the form controllers placed within the repeated area are not responding to user input as they should. For example, in the following code snippet, jqm will render a list of flip switches but they won’t flip !!

```
<ul  data-bind="foreach: [1, 2, 3, 4]" data-role="listview"> 
    <li>
        <select class="flip-a" data-role="slider">
            <option value="on">Yes!!</option>
            <option value="off">No</option>
        </select>        
    </li>
<ul>
```

I replaced the actual ko observableArray with a simple array to keep the code snippet small. 
I have tried the same with container less binding and found the results to be the same as the above example.

Much appreciate if someone can point out what I am doing wrong

jsf: http://jsfiddle.net/Chintana/6YRtr/

Thank you in advance

Chintana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a clash between knockout and jqueryui mobile in this case. I think it has to do with the order of how things are created. ie First jqueryui mobile sees the template and creates the button, then knockout replicates the code four times... I think this makes it all a bit underfined... Here is example code to fix it up:

```
<ul id="list" data-bind="foreach: [1, 2, 3, 4]" data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <select class="flip-a" data-bind="attr: { 'data-role': 'slider' }" data-role='nojs'>
            <option value="on">Yes!!</option>
            <option value="off">No</option>
        </select>        
    </li>
<ul>
```

And the js...

```
ko.applyBindings();
$('#list').trigger('create');
```

In this case the first pass of jqueryui mobile ignore the template (nojs option). Then the knockout binding occurs, which will create the four items, then we force a refresh of the list by calling the trigger('create') command. Because the real items are bound their data-role will be 'slider' and they are correctly transformed.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dWCDw/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [flip toggle switch documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/), it states:

> Set the for attribute of the label to match the id of the input so they are semantically associated. It's possible to accessibly hide the label if it's not desired in the page layout, but we require that it is present in the markup for semantic and accessibility reasons.

You will need to create a unique id though... Note the 'for' with apostrophes is there on purpose - makes it work in older IE versions.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: [1, 2, 3, 4]" data-role="listview"> 
    <li>
        <label class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-bind="attr: { 'for': 'flip' + $data }"></label>
        <select class="flip-a" data-role="slider" data-bind="attr: { id: 'flip' + $data }">
            <option value="on">Yes!!</option>
            <option value="off">No</option>
        </select>        
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Hi Felix, this did not solved the issue. I have added a jsf for your convenience http://jsfiddle.net/Chintana/6YRtr/

Comment: Awesome, that helped a lot... I have an answer for you but it is way different from the above... See my new answer shortly